# How do I share a python query page in facebook

Tags: python, facebook

Because my webpage includes a variable in the url I understand I need to encode it for the facebook sharer.  So in Python I'm encoding the url like this.

```
FBurl = "http://whatsonpontyclun.appspot.com/EventDetails?uid=" + str(e.key.id())
FBurl = urllib.quote(FBurl.encode('utf8'))
FBurl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + FBurl
values['FBurl'] = FBurl
template = jinja_environment.get_template('add-event2.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(values))
```

add-event2.html has the following in

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{FBurl}}" class="icon" data-type="social" data-value="facebook" title="facebook">
    <img src = "./static/img/facebook.jpg" width="40" alt="Show your business here" border="0">
</a>
```

which means the html actually produced for the server is

```
<a target="_blank" href="https%3A//www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php%3Fu%3Dhttp%3A//whatsonpontyclun.appspot.com/EventDetails%3Fuid%3D5799236641751040" class="icon" data-type="social" data-value="facebook" title="facebook"> 
    <img src = "./static/img/facebook.jpg" width="40" alt="Show your business here" border="0"> 
</a>
```

When I click the icon, the url called is
whatsonpontyclun.appspot.com/https%3A//www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php%3Fu%3Dhttp%3A//whatsonpontyclun.appspot.com/EventDetails%3Fuid%3D5799236641751040

Why is whatsonpontyclun.appspot.com being added to the front?

Comment: because `https%3A//www.facebook.com/[...]` is not a valid absolute url, your browser interprets it as a relative url, thus prepending your current domain.

Comment: Doesn't really help me.  Because I'm passing a variable I need to encode the address the facebook picks up.  How do I do that in python?  What am I doing wrong

Comment: You need to `urlencode` the url parameter, yes. You must not encode the facebook url though.